# Is is possible to send sms using Gluonhq mobile module api?

Tags: android, ios, javafx, gluon-mobile

I would like to know if it's possible to access sim card services like SMS using gluonhq mobile API.
Please help me as I am planning to design a prototype JavaFX mobile app that can run on android/ios devices and can send/receive SMSes.

Please let me know if any built-in APIs are there in Gluonhq mobile module, or any third-party open-source platform-independent libraries are there.

Regards,
Nirav Pradhan

Comment: Haven't worked with gluon-mobile yet, but iirc it has access to at least some of the android classes. If it has access to the `Intent` functionality, the best approach would probably be to construct the appropriate intent to open the sms app installed on the system. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

Comment: hi fabian,
    thanks for the response. i will definately try out the things you shared and will share with you the outcome. currently i got busy with other stuff.. thanks again for sharing yr knowledge.

regards,

Comment: Gluon has not yet provided rich features. but you can write your own services bases on your need.